# Lights on One Circuit Breaker Dim and Go Out. Host of Other Issues as Well

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, circuit-breaker

**Summary (TL;DR)**

Several lightbulbs in my home supplied by one circuit breaker dim over time and go out in about a year.  Right now, the ceiling light in my living room won't turn on at all.  It will turn on, go dim for 1-10 seconds, and then shut off completely.  There are a host of other electrical issues in the other rooms supplied by the same breaker.

**Details**

I'm an idiot.    For the longest time, I thought it was the lightbulbs or the fixtures.  Maybe, it is.  ¯(ツ)/¯   Here are the details.

- The single circuit breaker (15 amps) supplies power to 2 small bedrooms, a small bathroom, a mini-hallway, and a small living room. (I live in a very small house. )
- The house was built in about 1950. I don’t know when the main panel was replaced but we purchased our home about 15 years ago.
- The circuit breakers in my home have rarely tripped. The last time was years ago.
- PSE&G has been doing work in my neighborhood for the past few years. I would get emails stating that they had done work.  But, the power in my home turns off periodically.  Maybe, once every 1-3 months?

**Living Room - MAJOR ISSUE!**

- The ceiling fixture contains 2 LED lightbulbs. I replaced it a few months ago, thinking the light fixture was the problem. A few weeks ago, the LED lightbulbs were already very dim after a few months.
- Right now, the lights won’t remain on. I will turn it off and on. The light will momentarily turn on for 1-10 seconds, dim to a very low light, and then turn off completely.

**Bathroom**

- LED lightbulbs dim relatively quickly in about a year or two and eventually go out.
- The light switch has a night light that is constantly flickering. Occasionally, the lights won’t turn on. I have to turn it off and on a few times. This happens rarely though.

**Bedroom 1**

- One of the power outlets had an issue. Again, I can’t remember too many details because it was years ago. At the time, I tried to replace the outlet because it burned something out. I think I discovered that the wires were crossed. The white wire was actually “hot” and the white wire was “neutral”. That shocked me so I just covered the receptacle and it hasn’t been used since.

**Bedroom 2**

- In the past, while unplugging a phone charger, sparks would appear.

I hope I gave you enough details to figure this out!

So, can anyone make an educated guess on what’s going on?

Would checking the voltage and amp at an outlet with a multimeter help?

Is the circuit breaker defective supplying too much power to that part of the house?

Should I replace the circuit breaker?

Or, is overloading occurring because the circuit breaker supplies too many rooms?

What is the likelihood that the electricity company caused this?

Comment: Check voltage with a multimeter. In particular, try to check *both* hot legs - easiest if you have an electric clothes dryer as those are almost always plug-in. You want to see ~ 120V (can be anywhere from 110V to 125V) on each leg **and almost exactly the same on the other leg**. If you see 115V on on and 125V on the other, or any other variance more than 1V then you likely have a panel or **utility** problem. If the problem varies depending on when you turn on/off 240V appliances (clothes dryer, electric water heater, electric cooktop or oven) then it is even worse. Report what you find.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If comfortable with testing/checking connections you can do it yourself, but if not, getting an electrician in to check will be good.  Doing it yourself will require testing of live circuits and/or turning off the breaker, checking again that the power is off at the light/switch/outlet and checking if the connections are tight/right.  This can and should be done slowly.  Taking pictures if removing any wires.

Comment: Thanks.  Will get to it today and report what I find.